# Storing product stock changes in a separate table (database design)

Tags: database-design

I'm working on a project that has a **products** table, at the moment there is a *stock* field.

The issue is we don't know when stock is added, who's adding it

I was thinking of having a **product_stock** database which could add rows for each addition or subtraction, however I'm not sure as to how to calculate the total stock every time?

```
product: id, name
product_stock: product_id, change
```

##### Calculating the current supply?

If I perform a sum query each time, won't that become an issue once the database grows?

```
SELECT SUM(change) FROM product_stock WHERE product_id = 1
```

Is there a best practice for handling a situation like this?

Comment: How much other detail are you storing regarding when the item is stocked?  Are these Products physical items that must be stored/tracked?

Comment: Also tag with the DBMS (if that has been decided)

Answer (score 2):

Probably not a single best practice.  A lot depends on what you're using the data for and what your reporting needs really look like.

For basic needs, I'd probably keep a `stock` column in the `product` table and have a `product_history` that stores the history of what was in the product table (many database engines have built-in support for temporal tables to do this sort of thing automatically).  So you'd have a history table that looks something like this

```
product_id  name   stock  date        user
1           Widget 100    2021-01-01  Bob
1           Widget 150    2021-01-02  Jane
1           Widget  75    2021-01-03  Steve
```

and you could run a report that did a diff between rows to say that Jane added 50 units on Jan 2 and Steve removed 75 units on Jan 3.  Assuming that 99% of operational reports are really just looking for who did what over a relatively recent time frame and most of the attributes of the table are reasonably stable over time (no one is changing a product name on a daily basis), the cost of doing the subtraction a few times should be minimal assuming reasonable indexing.  This also has the lovely benefit that when the business comes back in a month wanting to know who changed the product name from "Widget" to "Wild Wilbur's Weally Wonky Widget" that the `product_history` table already tracks that information.

If you go with a `stock_history` table similar to what you're proposing with the `change` column, you'd likely have to have a process that reconciled the value in the `product` table because there will be bugs in the application that cause the two to drift and adds appropriate adjusting entries.  That's not totally unreasonable particularly in an inventory system where organizations are pretty accustomed to doing periodic counts and comparing that to what the system thinks the company should have because inevitably those two are not in sync due to theft, wastage, deliveries that were short/ long without anyone noticing, etc.  Or you can skip the reconciliation if no one needs the data to balance perfectly.  If a cute cat video on Facebook shows a total of 1,000,000 likes but the `like_history` table tallies 1,000,001 votes, no one is likely to lose too much sleep.

If you're doing long-term reporting off the history tables (i.e. you want to sum up how many units Jane has ordered in total over the 20 years she's been with the company or you want to aggregate orders by department) then you're likely in the realm of wanting separate reporting structures which would often mean some form of data warehouse (which I'm defining very broadly here rather than, say, a textbook [Kimball data warehouse](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/)) where you periodically materialize pre-aggregated results (i.e. totals by product by user by day) that you can then quickly roll up if some user wants totals by product by year because you're then just adding up at most 365 rows of daily data.

If you keep the `stock_history` table but get rid of `stock` from the `product` table to avoid that bit of denormalization, the cost of summing data for your reports probably isn't huge.  If you're changing the stock 10 times per product per day, that's only a few thousand rows to aggregate per year or a couple tens of thousands to aggregate over a decade.  That's probably not a tremendous lift for most systems and reporting needs.  If you're changing the stock thousands of times per product per day or you need to run a lot of queries that need aggregate a lot more rows than that (say you're running it for every product in the system rather than just one product), then you'd likely want to to be in the mode of periodically aggregating and storing off data.  So rather than summing 20 years of data, perhaps you have a nightly process that saves off the totals by product by user by day and then when someone runs a query you sum that value with the changes recorded today to get the answer.